# Price elasticity

Tags: economics

If $P = 90 – 0.05Q$ is the demand function for calculators in an engineering college.

(a) Derive expression for $\epsilon$ in terms of (i) $P$ only, (ii) $Q$ only.

(b) Calculate the value $\epsilon$ when the calculators are priced at $P = £20; £30; £70$.

(c) Determine the number of calculators demanded when $\epsilon = – 1$ and $\epsilon = 0$.
of demand.

(d) Use $\epsilon$ to calculate the response ($\%$ change in $Q$) to a $10\%$ increase in the price of calculators
at each of the following prices: $P = £20; £30; £45; £70; £90$.

Comment: What have you tried?  You should have a definition of elasticity.  Please look it up and quote it.  Then where are you stuck trying to apply it?

Comment: I did missed the class from the lecture, and this the only part i did not understand from this chapter

Comment: I believe the definition is the partial derivative of the quantity with respect to price, but I don't want to assume that for an answer.

Comment: or u know someone who knows how to do that could help, i need this urgent..

Comment: https://pressbooks.bccampus.ca/uvicecon103/chapter/4-2-elasticity/

Answer (score 1):

The price elasticity of demand is defined by
$$
\epsilon_{Q,P}=\epsilon = \frac{dQ/Q}{dP/P}=\frac{d\log(Q)}{d\log(P)},
$$ i.e. percentage change of $Q$ in response to a one percent change in price. So if $P=90-0.05Q$, then we have
$$
\epsilon = \frac{dQ}{dP}\frac{P}{Q}=\frac{-20P}{Q}=\frac{-1800+Q}{Q}=\frac{P}{P-90.}
$$ For (b) and (c), just plug the value in the above expression and solve the equation. For (d), calculate $10\epsilon$ when $P=20,30,\ldots, 90$.

Comment: can i know what should i type in youtube to get to know this topic?  I cant really found this topic in youtube, thanks for the solution btw

Comment: @TeeSanAik I'm not very familiar with the youtube, so I may not be able to guide you. Perhaps such keywords like 'elasticity', 'microeconomics', 'marginal', etc would help?

Comment: alright thanks much!